# Is there a way to force Finder to show folder sizes within search results, or a workaround?

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur, apple-silicon

I have "Calculate all sizes" selected, and outside of search results, Finder calculates and reports folder sizes. As soon as I run a search, however, if the search results contain folders their size is not shown.

Is there a way to force Finder to show folder sizes in search results, or a workaround?

macOS Big Sur 11.4
M1 MacBook Pro, 16GB, 2TB